# node js - как получить инфо о функции которая вызвала callback в вызываемом callback?

Tags: node.js

// Простите за дилетантский вопрос...

// такое возможно?

```
    function testMain(a,cb) {
    a++;
    return cb(a);
    };

    function testSlave(_a) {
    console.log('res:',_a);
    // как тут определить, что вызов именно от "testMain"?
    };

    testMain(1,testSlave);
```

... :-(

Comment: Если Вам это требуется, значит Вы что-то делаете не правильно.

Comment: Боюсь если вы не знаете поставленной задачи, то вывод делаете рано. А если уж применительно к вопросу, необходимость состояла в контроле процесса вызывающего callback и применение - безопасность. Суть всего не могу писать, есть причины.. Думаю вы меня поймете. Спасибо.

Comment: Если это не задача из какого-нибудь учебника, а встретилась в реальной жизни, значит что-то в вашей архитектуре точно криво.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function testMain(a,cb) {
    a++;
    return cb(a);
    };

    function testSlave(_a) {
        var mainFn = testSlave.caller.toString().match(/function ([^(]*)\(/)[1];
    console.log('result:',_a,'main_proc:',mainFn);

    };

    testMain(1,testSlave);
```

...исправил
Всем спасибо...